# Why am I seeing subtle horizontal lines? (Intel HD Graphics 4000)

Tags: mojave, graphics, gpu

I can't take screenshot of it and a picture taken with an iPhone doesn't show it, but here is an exaggeration of what it looks like (visible all over the screen):

[image: looks like this]

It appeared very recently; probably linked to upgrading to Mojave a few days ago.

[image: system info]

Any solution that doesn't require a visit at the Apple Store / a repair shop would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general guide, if it doesn't show up in a screen-shot, it's a hardware fault.

Potential fail-points are the monitor's video cable, the screen, or the graphics chip itself.
Unless you fancy stripping it apart yourself to try to re-seat or replace the video cable, I think a trip to the repair shop is on the cards.

iFixit do some good teardown & repair guides, if you want to tackle something like this yourself - [MacBook Pro Repair](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro) - though you'd need to see if they have one for your specific model.

Comment: thanks a lot, yes should have expected this as the answer, I'm going to go to some repair shop, maybe apple store too

Comment: Weigh the cost of a repair against replacing it with one a bit newer, second hand. Sometimes it's better economic sense to quit while you're ahead. Make any repair shop give you a firm quote before committing.

Comment: hard to find qwerty keyboards where I am, gonna try though, thanks